# Rewrite /a/1/2 to /a.php using Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex

I'm taking over a really old app and migrating it from apache to nginx.

What I currently have. This works:

```
# catch specific paths, rewrite to first segment
# /a/1/2 => a.php
# /b/3/4 => b.php
# /c/5/6 => c.php

rewrite ^/(a|b|c)(/.*)?$ /$1.php last;

# all other paths go to index.php    
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.php$args;
}
```

However, in my actual file, `(a|b|c)` is like 100 segments long. What I'd like to do is write a regexp to replace it

I tried this

```
# rewrite first segment of path as /a/1/2 => a.php
location ~* ^/([a-z_]+)(/.*)?$ {
  try_files $uri /$1.php$args /index.php$args;
}

# all other paths to index.php
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.php$args;
}
```

But it's not working :{

**Problem:** When I go to `/a/1/2` nginx actually *downloads* the `a.php` file instead of serving it

Comment: Read how `try_files` works

Comment: Care to elaborate some more? I'm clearly missing something, but I don't know what.

Comment: _the processing is performed in the current context_. And your current content has notthing about processing PHP files, so nginx just serves them as any other static file.

Comment: @AlexeyTen why does `try_files ... /home.php` work then? If no match is found in `...`, nginx will pass `home.php` along to PHP instead of serving `home.php` as a download. Is this special last file argument to `try_files` ?

Comment: Have you read docs?

Comment: @AlexeyTen ok, i understand the internal redirect is only used for the last argument now, but that doesn't really put me much closer to understanding how to solve my problem - at least, not in an elegant way.